# ASP.Net MVC Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename' and i not using AttachDBFilename on connectionString

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

my issue is the next:

I'm trying to connect remotely to Sql Server 2008 with Entity Framework on my MVC Application and it's throwing "Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename', when i never set this property on my ConnectionString.

I have Sql Server and the mvc app deployed on different servers. When i deploy on my local IIS this issue not occur but when i deploy on the test server pufff throw the error...

The ConnectionString look like this:

```
<add name="lalalala" connectionString="Data Source=ServerIP;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=MyDb;User Id=user;Password=secret"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: I would guess you have a stray web.config somewhere on your server that is being picked up.

Answer (score 0):

It is in your machine.config, there is a default connection string stored there.